# Please give me an ArrayFormula for this formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, line-breaks

I want to achieve column I.

Formula is:
`=textjoin(char(10),false,A4:F4)`

When I convert to Arrayfromula:
`=transpose(split(textjoin(char(10),false,{ArrayFormula("~"&A4:A),A4:F}),"~"))`

[image]
[Editable Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ar4LvFDiFyaxVCnHMkmq-9JUHOlYA8U8_CCVTQh903I/edit?usp=sharing)

In my Arrayformula the first value is repeating, Please Help!

**EDIT:**

Is there any way to achieve **Arrayformula 1** (two columns) & **Arrayformula 2** (single column)?

Numbers sheet:
*(Basically not include cells with value 0)*
[image]

**The formula should even work with Strings as data not compulsorily Numbers as shown below:**

Strings & Numbers sheet:
*(Basically not include cells with value 0 & NULL)*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 TO_TEXT(A4:F6)&"×"),,9^9)), "×", CHAR(10)), " ", ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A4:F),,
 9^9)))="",,JOIN(CHAR(10), A1:F1)), 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 TO_TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A4:F, " ", "♀"))&"×"),,
 9^9)), "×", CHAR(10)), " |\n$", ), "♀", " ")})
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A4:F),,9^9)))="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 TO_TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A4:F="",,A1:F1&": "&A4:F), " ", "♀"))&"×"),,
 9^9)), "×", CHAR(10)), " |\n$", ), "♀", " ")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution adds an extra Line Break at last because of which the alignment gets messed up https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxLWW.jpg & also if this is used with strings it removes the spaces in between https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXCPz.jpg, any way we could remove the extra Line Break & make it work with strings too?

Comment: If possible can you please answer my edited question too?

Comment: I got the formula which removes the extra Line break & which works with Strings too: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(A4:F7)&"×"),,9^9)),"× ",CHAR(10)),"×",))` still **didn't** get the EDITED question answer!